# CSV file doesnt recognize text symbols

Tags: csv, text, unicode, format

I download a csv file online. However, when I open it, it does not recognize all the symbols, making it difficult to read.

See below example of how it shows the text and next to it how it should have shown the text:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVSxr.png)

Is there a way to solve this?

File is in Unicode (UTF-8).

Comment: The problem is your viewer isn’t using UTF8 to decode the file. If it is Excel, convert the file to UTF8 with BOM or use a different viewer. Notepad++ can both view it correctly and convert it if needed.